# As what user does a command end up executing?

Tags: users, group

How can I find out as what user a command executes? (I'm running Ubuntu, but I suspect the answer applies to Unix in general).

What I'm trying to do is [get `msmtp` running](http://devblog.virtage.com/2013/05/email-sending-from-ubuntu-server-via-google-apps-smtp-with-msmtp/comment-page-1/) and logging to `/var/log/msmtp`. I've set the owner and group of that file to `mail`, then added my user to the mail group via `sudo adduser dandv mail`:

```
$ ls -al /var/log/msmtp.log
-rw-rw---- 1 mail mail 0 Jul 24 18:45 /var/log/msmtp.log
$ groups dandv
dandv : dandv mail sudo
```

Yet when when I run

```
cat testmail | msmtp dan@example.org -v
```

I get a permission denied:

```
msmtp: cannot log to /var/log/msmtp.log: cannot open: Permission denied
```

What is msmtp's problem?

Comment: `groups dandv` tells you what groups the user `dandv` would get if he logged in now. Run `groups` with no argument to see what groups your session's processes are in.

Answer (score 0):

Uh. Apparently I had to logout and login again for my user's addition to the `mail` group to take effect. Lame.